# How do I format EditText to this specific format in android?

Tags: android, regex, android-edittext, format

The format I want the input to be is 00XXX0000 format, 0 for numbers and X for words. How I do I check that on a button click? Can regular expression be used? What would be the best way to do this?

for example 14BMC0088 would be an acceptable format.

Comment: for example 14BMC0088 would be an acceptable format.

Comment: That means `X` for letter?

Comment: yes.
Is there any better way than using regex?

Comment: Check my answer, also please update your question..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it using Pattern and Matcher

```
public boolean checkPattern() {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^\\d{2}[a-zA-Z]{3}\\d{4}$");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(rollNoVar);
        if(matcher.find())
        {
            return  true;
        }
        else
           return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Regex (consider `X` as letter and `0` as digit, as per comment):

```
^\d{2}[a-zA-Z]{3}\d{4}$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cM2tK4/1)

Comment: Thank you. I have added how I executed it just in case anyone finds it helpful.

Comment: @nandu Do you think its fair to remove my answer as selected and select your own one instead after so many days?